# How to stop iTunes to auto download "Available apps" on start?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore

I have downloaded few apps on my iDevice and stopped the download realizing that was not the intended app.Whenever I start my iTunes, it tries to download them.

How can I stop the apps from getting downloaded ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `iTunes` Menu Item => `Preferences` => `iTunes Store` => `Disable Apps under Automatic Downloads`

[image: Disable Apps under Automatic Downloads]